TokenAndPositionEmbedding missing in keras_nlp.layers
ImportError: cannot import name 'TokenAndPositionEmbedding' from 'keras_nlp.layers'
Packages installed (Windows OS)
tensorflow Version: 2.17.0
keras Version: 3.5.0
keras-nlp Version: 0.0.2
Code:
from keras_nlp.layers import TokenAndPositionEmbedding, TransformerEncoder, TransformerDecoder
decoder_embedding = TokenAndPositionEmbedding(len(target_tokenizer.word_index) + 1, sequence_len, embed_dim)(decoder_input)
Tried:
pip install keras-nlp==0.15.1
Collecting keras-nlp==0.15.1
Using cached keras_nlp-0.15.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.7 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py in  \python\python312\lib\site-packages (from keras-nlp==0.15.1) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in  \python\python312\lib\site-packages (from keras-nlp==0.15.1) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in  \python\python312\lib\site-packages (from keras-nlp==0.15.1) (24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: regex in  \python\python312\lib\site-packages (from keras-nlp==0.15.1) (2024.9.11)
Requirement already satisfied: rich in  \python\python312\lib\site-packages (from keras-nlp==0.15.1) (13.8.1)
Collecting kagglehub (from keras-nlp==0.15.1)
Using cached kagglehub-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (21 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of keras-nlp to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-text; platform_system != "Darwin" (from keras-nlp) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-text; platform_system != "Darwin"

This is available in keras_nlp 0.15,  you probably have a too old version.


I tried to upgrade keras-nlp but getting conflict issues during installing keras-nlp-nightly.
Upgrading to keras-nlp only installs 0.0.2. Uninstalling & installing still installs 0.0.2. pip is unable to determine which version of it suits with other installed packages.


I am currently using tensorflow_version 2.17 and I tried with this command
!pip install keras_nlp and the code works .Please refer to this gist
